# How do I fix my DNS on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

I am running Ubuntu 23.04 and I cannot resolve nameservers. When I run `resolvectl status` I get the following:

```
Global
      Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=n0/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: uplink

Link 2 (ens224)
Current Scopes:none
      Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=n0/unsupported
```

I have read many posts, but I am unsure where to fix this, partially because I am on 23.04.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Were you hoping [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) would configure 8.8.8.8 or some other address? Tell us about the client + server DHCP setup, and what query / response packets are revealed by tcpdump or wireshark. Does e.g. `$ dig mx gmail.com @8.8.8.8` succeed?

Comment: @J_H I have tried DHCP, Manual, tried setting the nameservers in the resolv.conf file. Nothing has worked. My other machines work fine, this one broke after I did an update.

Comment: You're not really giving us much to work with, here. Something changed with the version upgrade. Many config files were affected. Show us the debugging effort you have put into this.

Comment: @J_H Well, if you look at the status of resolv.conf, which I posted above, I do not have any DNS entries. My system is using NetManager, and I have used automatic DNS entries and manual DNS entries in NetManager, however my resolv.conf remains empty. Maybe this is correct for 23.04?? I do not know, and I am not well versed in Linux DNS management to understand how resolve is supposed to work.

Comment: If I ping anything using DNS, I get the message: `Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: Well, if you mean ICMP, then a command like `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` is what would make sense on your host. But a DNS query is of greater interest, like the `dig mx gmail.com @8.8.8.8` command that I requested output on. It (1) doesn't need a resolv.conf file since we _gave_ the nameserver IP as an argument, and (2) it can suggest whether manually stuffing 8.8.8.8 into resolv.conf would even work in your case -- it shows if we have UDP port 53 connectivity. Once we know that, then we can worry about DHCP debugging so that a nice resolv.conf will be produced upon bootup.

Comment: @J_H I get a `communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: timed out` message.

Comment: @J_H I also checked `01-network-manager-all.yaml` and this is what was returned:
`# Let NetworkManager manage all of the devices on this system
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager`
My understanding is there should be DNS entries here, like this:
`# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4`

Comment: _"I get .. timed out"_ Well, that is Bad. I don't know what's going on with your path to internet, and what ACLs and filters the various routers might implement. But if `dig` can't get a port 53 response from google, then resolv.conf clients won't either. You want to figure that out first, and _then_ worry about DHCP putting the right thing in resolv.conf.

Comment: @J_H Okay, this is strange behavior I do not understand. If I set the VM to DHCP vs. manual and change the route in the FW to the DHCP IP, it can get out. Once I return to manual and update the route, it fails again. This makes absolutely no sense.